# google maps v3 marker mouseover tooltip

Tags: google-maps, tooltip, mouseover, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to put a tooltip made myself with divs when the mouse is over a marker, but I don't know how to get the screen position to put the div on the correct position, here is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
            divover.css("left", marker.get("left"));
            divover.css("top", marker.get("top"));
            divover.css("display", "block");
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
            divover.css("display", "none");
});
```

Obviously the get method fails. Any Idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a tricky one. In v2 of the API, you can do:

```
map.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getLatLng(), zoomLevel);
```

In v3, the method fromLatLngToContainerPixel has been moved to the MapCanvasProjection object. To get a MapCanvasProjection object, you need to call getProjection on an OverlayView object. It looks like the Marker class is extended from OverlayView, but unfortunately it doesn't have the getProjection method. I have no idea why - may be worth filing a bug.

The way I've done it is by creating my own custom marker class, based on OverlayView, so it still has the getProjection method:

```
var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng_);
```

You can read Google's tutorial on [custom overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) or copy their [example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, finally I did that, but something that I could resolve on 2 lines of code, was extremely complex and it took me serveral hours

Comment: It should be a lot easier, so I submitted this bug: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2342

When (if) it's fixed, `var point = marker.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(marker.getPosition());`
 should work.

Answer (score 10):

Here is link to a tutorial I just created on how to create a tooltip for Google Maps API V3: http://medelbou.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/creating-a-tooltip-for-google-maps-javascript-api-v3/
To see it in action, go here http://medelbou.com/demos/google-maps-tooltip/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Especially as the demo now 404s. :)

Answer (score 5):

`infowindow` is designed to solve this problem.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows

Comment: This is far the most practical solution. I mean, if you don't wanna code your own popup-info.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow, none of the other answer worked for me or I didn't want to implement them (e.g. [creating your own custom Marker class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727482/177710)).

After some more searching I found [this solution](http://a32.me/2012/03/position-custom-and-fancy-overlay-dialog-on-google-maps-v3/), though, that does **exactly** what's needed:

```js
function latlngToPoint(map, latLng) {
    var topRight = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
    var bottomLeft = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
    var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
    var worldPoint = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
    var point = new google.maps.Point((worldPoint.x - bottomLeft.x) * scale, (worldPoint.y - topRight.y) * scale);
    return point;
}
```

Then just call `var position = latlngToPoint(map, marker.getPosition());` and use the position to your heart's content :-)

Comment: oops. spoke to soon. it works in some cases and not in others. kinda baffled by the variability.

Comment: @elrobis: Are you saying you're having a problem with the code in my answer? Do you get any errors in the Javascript console of your browser? What's the broken behavior?

Comment: ahh hey man. no got it working later but I'd already closed this page. I did something stupid like assigning the `.x` value to both the `x` and `y` positions. And since I had a test map centered on a point (so `x` and `y` were nearly the same), it seemed to be working, but the points around it behaved wacky. So at first it seemed to work--the comment I deleted--then I checked the other points and thought I spoke too soon. Then later when I was going mad, I realized I'd reused one of the values. ::head slap:: smh.. :/

Comment: Thanks, a lot better than the chosen answer

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble getting the projection to update after dragging the map using the method here or creating a dummy overlayview and using its projection. I found a solution that works 100% for me here: http://qfox.nl/notes/116

```
/**
* @param {google.maps.Map} map
* @param {google.maps.LatLng} latlng
* @param {int} z
* @return {google.maps.Point}
*/
var latlngToPoint = function(map, latlng, z){
    var normalizedPoint = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latlng); // returns x,y normalized to 0~255
    var scale = Math.pow(2, z);
    var pixelCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(normalizedPoint.x * scale, normalizedPoint.y * scale);
    return pixelCoordinate; 
};
/**
* @param {google.maps.Map} map
* @param {google.maps.Point} point
* @param {int} z
* @return {google.maps.LatLng}
*/
var pointToLatlng = function(map, point, z){
    var scale = Math.pow(2, z);
    var normalizedPoint = new google.maps.Point(point.x / scale, point.y / scale);
    var latlng = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(normalizedPoint);
    return latlng; 
};
```

Comment: Not exactly sure why, but this solution didn't work for me, the coordinates were still off. I found, however, this solution: http://a32.me/2012/03/position-custom-and-fancy-overlay-dialog-on-google-maps-v3/ - and that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674392/how-to-access-google-maps-api-v3-markers-div-and-its-pixel-position):

```
var point = gmap.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition())
```

Comment: this does not give the screen pixel relative to the upper-left corner. Instead it gives the world co-ordinate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MarkerWithLabel` to render markers, you could easily use its `label` property to display extra data when mousing over

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (ev) {
    this.labelContentOld = this.labelContent
    this.set("labelContent", this.id + ' ' + this.labelContent)
  })
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function (ev) {
    this.set("labelContent", this.labelContentOld)
  })
```