# How do I assign a css id to a marker in Google Maps V3 API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, maps

How do I assign a css id to a marker in Google Maps V3 API?

I am attempting to dynamically assign all pointers with an id after an SQL query so I can alter certain overlays based on moused over markers.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning an ID to a marker probably won't work. However, google maps API can offer you mouseover events for markers, which would probably work for you?

Maybe this will help: [google maps v3 marker mouseover tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669727/google-maps-v3-marker-mouseover-tooltip)